# nativescript-angular: unable to set a dropdown vale as selected by default

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have a dropdown list in my page. I am trying to keep a particular value as selected by default.

I used `[selectedIndex]="selectedIndex"` for this purpose
But the value is not getting set as selected.

**fruit.component.html**

```
    <StackLayout orientation='horizontal' height="80" width="100%">
        <DropDown class="dropdown"  [items]="fruitsList" hint="Select" #fruit 
             [(ngModel)]="selectedFruitIndex" [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex" 
            (selectedIndexChanged)="onDropdownChange($event)" (opened)="onDropdownOpen()" 
            android:marginBottom="-20" ios:marginBottom="0" (closed)="onDropdownClose()">
        </DropDown>
    </StackLayout>
```

**fruit.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { SelectedIndexChangedEventData } from 'nativescript-drop-down';

@Component({
    selector: "fruit",
    templateUrl: "./fruit.component.html",
    styleUrls: ['./fruit.component.scss']
})
export class FruitComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('fruit', { static: true }) fruit: ElementRef;
    selectedFruitIndex: any;
    selectedIndex: number = 0;
    fruitsList: string[] = [];
    constructor() {
        this.fruitsList.push("Apple"); //keep this as selected by defaullt
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fruitsList.push("Orange");
        this.fruitsList.push("Grapes");
      }

    ddOpen(): void {
        if (isIOS) {
            if (this.fruit.nativeElement.selectedIndex == null) {
                this.fruit.nativeElement.selectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    ddClose() {
        if (isIOS) {
            this.selectedIndex = this.selectedFruitIndex;
        }
    }

    onddChange(args: SelectedIndexChangedEventData) {
        if (isAndroid) {
            this.selectedIndex = args.newIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `this.fruit.nativeElement.selectedIndex = 0;` inside `ngOnInit()` ? It should work

Comment: Is it a iOS specific issue? It doesn't show the right value in the Label Or the right index in the spinner?

Comment: I'm testing this on Android. Idk about iOS. It doesn't show the value as selected by default in android. @Manoj

Comment: Tried that. I'm getting an error in Android. TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined @Shashank Vivek

Comment: It seems to work just fine on my end. I'm unsure why you have both `ngModel` and `selectedIndex` / `selectedIndexChange` events. Technically ngModel operates on selectedIndex, so just one of them will be sufficient. If you still have issues, please share a Playground Sample.

Comment: @Manoj https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0fMUcK&v=4

Comment: @Lonewolf : My bad, please check it in `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook. You need to consider lifecycle hook as well

Comment: @Shashank Vivek I tried it on ngAfterViewInit() hook. Now the error is gone but dropdown value is not getting set as default.

Comment: Where exactly you are importing Dropdown module? the sample shows empty page only.

Comment: I import it in home module page but in playground it's not possible to add dropdown package. I tried adding it, but still it shows package not found. @Manoj

Comment: It's very much possible to use this plugin, you just to adjust your import statement to be relative to current path - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0fMUcK&v=5 As I already mentioned you are suppose to use either ngModel / selectedIndex, using both doesn't make any sense because ngModel itself operates on selectedIndex. Also when you submit a Playground please make sure it has the complete code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Lonewolf : can u create a stackblitz demo. I need to debug the code. Its difficult to guess from this much info. +1 , not sure why a downvote

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=0fMUcK&v=5 @Shashank Vivek

Comment: @Lonewolf this links asks for QR scan to run the code :( . I'll try to see it in sometime. Stackblitz dont ask for such things to run the code

Comment: I'm not able to add some npm packages in stackblitz and playground app. don't know why.

Comment: Any updates? @Shashank Vivek

Comment: @Lonewolf : I couldn't see a running code. so I didnt debug it. LEt me know which packages are not getting installed on stackblitz. It should be done easily

Comment: nativescript-drop-down package @Shashank Vivek